# How do you limit get_next_by_FOO inside a django view? code included

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I have used get_next_by_FOO inside my view to display an absolute url for the following item within a set of records however when it gets to the end of the query set an error is raised.

how do I stop my view from raising this error and instead just outputting some html letting me know that it has come to the end of the set?

All help is greatly appreciated.

Here is the error message, my view and template code.

Error

```
    Exception Type:     DoesNotExist
    Exception Value:    Body matching query does not exist.
```

View

```
def news_view(request, url):
news = get_object_or_404(Body, url=url)
next = news.get_next_by_published()
pre = news.get_previous_by_published()
return render_to_response('news/news_view.html', {
    'news': news,
    'pre': pre,
    'next': next
}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Template

```
    <a href="{{ next.get_absolute_url }}">Next News</a></p>
    <a href="{{ pre.get_absolute_url }}">Previous News</a></p>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The brute force answer is:

```
def news_view(request, url):
    news = get_object_or_404(Body, url=url)
    try:
        next = news.get_next_by_published()
    except Body.DoesNotExist:
        next = None
    try:
        pre = news.get_previous_by_published()
    except Body.DoesNotExist:
        pre = None
    return render_to_response('news/news_view.html', {
        'news': news,
        'pre': pre,
        'next': next
        }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Template:

```
{% if next %}<a href="{{ next.get_absolute_url }}">Next News</a></p>{% else %}<span class="disabled">At Last Item</span>{% endif %}
{% if pre %}<a href="{{ pre.get_absolute_url }}">Previous News</a></p>{% else %}<span class="disabled">At First Item</span>{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 4):

I do this:

```python
def news_view(request, url):
    news = get_object_or_404(Body, url=url)
    return direct_to_template(request, 'news/news_view.html', {'news': news,})
```

Template:

```html
{% with news.get_previous_by_pub_date as prev %}
   {% if prev %}
       <a class="left btn" href="{{ prev.get_absolute_url }}">Previous News</a>
   {% endif %}
{% endwith %}
{% with news.get_next_by_pub_date as next %}
    {% if next %}
        <a class="right btn" href="{{ next.get_absolute_url }}">Next News</a>
    {% endif %}
{% endwith %}
```